Is there a functional approach to extensible variant types in Scala like in Ocaml?
In Ocaml you can do the following:
type attr = ..

type attr += Str of string

type attr +=
    | Int of int
    | Float of float

Is there a version of this in Scala?
I know there is a way to implement this with classes as seen in this post, but is there a way to do this keeping it a functional program?
I want to be able to add to this type in completely different files without having to modify earlier code.

Sounds like algebraic data types and then apply pattern matching. Not sure what is you want to do. Could you provide some code or examples about what you want to do or what is the problem it brings you to do it in that way?

Classes are not strictly non-fp - mutating a type feels more anti-fp TBH

Mutating type feels more like an open class, where you can always add a new subtype. Pattern matching is still possible although it cannot be checked for exhaustiveness

In scala 3:
type SomeType = Int | Double
type RicherType = SomeType | String | List[Int]

def process(value: RicherType): Unit = value match {
  case i: Int        => println(s"Integer: $i")
  case d: Double     => println(s"Double: $d")
  case s: String     => println(s"String: $s")
  case l: List[Int]  => println(s"List of Ints: $l")
}

In scala 2:
sealed trait SomeType
case class IntType(value: Int) extends SomeType
case class DoubleType(value: Double) extends SomeType

sealed trait RicherType
case class StringType(value: String) extends RicherType
case class IntListType(value: List[Int]) extends RicherType
case class SomeTypeWrapper(value: SomeType) extends RicherType

def process(value: RicherType): Unit = value match {
  case StringType(s)                  => println(s"String: $s")
  case IntListType(l)                 => println(s"List of Ints: $l")
  case SomeTypeWrapper(IntType(i))    => println(s"Wrapped Integer: $i") 
  case SomeTypeWrapper(DoubleType(d)) => println(s"Wrapped Double: $d")
}


Is there a way to do this without renaming the type?

@AndrewFox what's the purpose? Maybe typeclass or extension would help.
